# convert txt into mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, import

SO, I have to convert txt files with format like this:

```
[name] John Smith

    [address]
    4260 Russell Road
    Kent, USA

    [e-mail] john.smith@something.com
    [familymember]
    - Lisa Smith
    - Randy Smith
    - Lauren Smith
    [contact] +1876543
```

Notice that all the field names is between `[` and `]`.
the value sometimes only one line, sometimes multiple lines. Some even have blank lines.

**Question:** how do I convert the data above into mysl, or even csv?

I have tried using excel to import the data, but it cannot handle the multiple line values without creating new rows for each lines.

Comment: Why don't you create a program on your own to convert the data? I don't think mysql has a facility to import from such format. Or try to change it into SQL Query..

Comment: What to do with [familymember] items? Do they need to be inserted as separate records into child table?

Comment: You have to clearly understand your txt file format and write your own program to parse data. For example, the [Address] followed with two lines, somehow you need to know they are one value. The [FamilyMember] followed with three lines, each of them is one value etc.

Comment: For family member, I think i will just put them in one record with carriage return. that's fine for now.
I figured it out how to convert all the data above using a Bulk Find&Replace software to convert all the "[]" sign into html table, than I bulk import them to Excel, then save it as CSV document :-p
not pretty, but it does the trick for now.
Thanks all